# Git: problems creating a repository

Tags: wordpress, git, github

I'm attempting to incorporate a WordPress website into Git.

I've created a local repository through GitHub for Mac, and I've edited the "Primary remote repository" to the HTTPS URL under the Settings tab, after which I've then [applied some ignore patterns](http://bigwilliam.com/gitignore-for-wordpress-projects/).

So far this has worked.

However, when I look at the items under the Changes tab, I'm seeing entries for the ".gitignore" file and everything in the "wp-content" folder but nothing above it.

I don't think it's the ignore patterns because some of the default WordPress templates are in there, and a load of OS items, each of which have been ignored, but I understand the ignore patterns won't be applied until after a commit.

At the bottom of the list of entries to commit, the path is correct and not within the "wp-content" folder.

So why are things like "wp-admin" and "wp-config.php" — or any other root item — missing?

Is there a maximum length to the number of items GitHub for Mac can show, but if so, why show "wp-content" when other items precede it in alphabetical order?

I'm a bit confused as to what's happening. At this point, nothing has been committed, and I'm hesitant to do so if part of the website is missing.

Comment: Can you show your directory structure (only to show the location of the `.git` directory)? Also, can you show your `.gitignore`?

Comment: @rnevius I'm not sure what mean in the first question. As for the second, you'll find a link to the ignore patterns in the post itself.

Comment: Whoever voted the question down, at least explain why, or your vote is pointless. I'm here to figure things out, and knowing where I've gone wrong is part of the learning process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the section that's causing it:

```
#===================================#
#     WP Core, except content       #
#===================================#
/*
!.gitignore
!wp-content/
# !media/
!favicon.ico
!favicon.png
!robots.txt
!humans.txt
```

Notice the leading `/*`. This means that it's ignoring EVERYTHING by default. From [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname.

The wildcard `*` then tells it to match everything in that path.

The exclamation point `!` then refers to items which explicitly should NOT be ignored.

Comment: But why would Git ignore some things but then not others, such as ".DS_Store"?

Comment: Look at the very top of the `.gitignore`. *.DS_Store* is explicitly listed to be ignored (in fact, it's the very first thing listed in the file).

Comment: Yes, I see that, but those items aren't being ignored, because there is a load of them among the items to commit. So why is Git not ignoring those but everything else?

Comment: What's your end goal? What do and don't you want committed? I don't understand why you're copying a .gitignore that doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: Being able to commit everything in the folder is the most important thing, whereas ignoring items is a fight that can wait. I'm going to remove the line you mentioned and then add the other folders by hand.

Comment: In the end, I just did everything by hand.